# Build ti.barcode failed

Tags: module, appcelerator, titanium-mobile, zxing

This is my first time to build Titanium module. What I am building is the ti.barcode for Android. I grasp the source code from Github and import to Titanium studio. Some build path error is easily corrected by opening build path and just close. There is no error shown on the project.

But when I tried to package it, I always get error message:

> Launching build and packaging failed
>   Build failed. Unable to locate generated zip file at /Users/ymlan/Code/ti.barcode-android-2.3.5/dist/ti.barcode-android-2.3.5.zip

I use `JDK 1.8` , `SDK 5.2.2GA` , it seems to be some configuration error, but I can not figure it out after hours of googling. Since I request your keens help here.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Cliff

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's related to https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/AC-3806.

It gives me the same error with a new module too.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. After two days of hell, I have found the cause of my problem! In my workspace root there was an old tiapp.xml (I do not know how it got there...). After removing it, I managed to make the build of the modules, both from Appcelerator Studio that from the CLI.
Try to see if you also have a tiapp.xml or timodule.xml file in the root of the workspace.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this one might help you 
https://github.com/acktie/Acktie-Mobile-Android-Barcode

Or is it definitely required to use Ti.barcode ?

Comment: Thank you very much, my dear friend, I will try this module. I just need to scan qrcode on Android. If this works, that will be great.