# Packaging Android Module error (Titanium SDK)

Tags: android, titanium, appcelerator, titanium-modules, titanium-android

I'm trying to compile a Titanium Module (android) but I'm getting this error:

> Launching build and packaging failed
>   Build failed. Unable to locate generated zip file at /Users/ricardo/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/flashcam-android/dist/pt.ricardo.flashcam-android-1.0.7.zip

I've found this recent question and JIRA ticket, but still, everything that solved the problem doesn't work for me.

https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/AC-3806

[Build ti.barcode failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37678090/build-ti-barcode-failed)

I've tried with 5.2.2.GA, 5.3.0.GA and 6.0.0.v20160620083247-osx.

I'm using a MacBook Pro with OSX 10.10.5

Answer (score 0):

try to see if you have a tiapp.xml or timodule.xml file in the root of the workspace. This could be the cause of the problem. Also, Make sure your NDK path is set correctly.

Comment: I've already check for that, I don't have any tiapp.xml or timodule.xml in the workspace root or in the module root folder. The NDK path is correct, yesterday I've also update the NDK version, but still no success

Comment: I've changed the location of android SDK and NDK (latest versions), downloaded all android API versions, I've the latest Titanium SDK, Titanium CLI, Java version, still nothing

Comment: I am also having the same problem on iOS..tried everything I could do like switching workspace, creating new module, removing old files..blah blah..., but never been in such problems after creating many modules...seems something is broken after recent updates...any luck @Ricardo???

Comment: Still no success, I'll do a full re-install of appcelerator studio and they I'll give feedback

Comment: @Prashant Saini, posted as an answer

Comment: That is not a feasible answer as we should never put anything inside Applications folder and it is nowhere mentioned to do so, but I have found the genuine solution for that issue on iOS. I will post it as an answer tonight.

Answer (score 0):

I've removed the Appcelerator Studio application and the Titanium folder inside Library/Application Support.

Placed the android SDK and NDK inside the applications folder, and install the studio again, and JDT, now it works.